# How to do internal redirecting in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I'm kinda new to react and was wondering how to internally redirect your pages in reactjs. I have two pages called register and register2. In register page, I just check if the email exists in the database or not and if it doesn't exist then it redirects to register2 page for creating the full account with username and password. However, in the address bar, it kinda looks ugly to show something like register2. So I was wondering if there is any way through which I can internally redirect without changing the address in the address bar to register2 such that it stays as register throughout the whole account creation process.

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-hawking-0to2x) to show the issue

register.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

import * as Yup from "yup";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      <Link color="inherit" href="sad">
        New1
      </Link>{" "}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {"."}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  form: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
  }
}));

const Reg = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState("");
  const [changed, setChanged] = useState(false);
  const [newpage, setNew] = useState(false);
  const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    const { email } = values;

    var body = {
      email: email
    };
    console.log(body);
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    const url = "/api/emailcheck";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const text = await response.text();
      setSubmitting(false);
      setChanged(false);
      setNew(true);
      console.log(text);
      if (newpage) {
        props.history.push({
          pathname: "/register2",
          state: { email }
        });
        // props.history.push(`/register2/${email}`);
      } else if (text === "exists") {
        props.history.push(`/`);
      } else {
        setLoginError("Email is invalid");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "" }}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      //********Using Yup for validation********/

      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .required("Required")
      })}
    >
      {props => {
        const {
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
          isSubmitting,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit
        } = props;
        return (
          <>
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
              <CssBaseline />
              <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                  <LockOutlinedIcon />
                </Avatar>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                  Sign in
                </Typography>
                <form
                  className={classes.form}
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                  noValidate
                >
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    id="email"
                    value={values.email}
                    label="Email Address"
                    name="email"
                    autoComplete="email"
                    onChange={e => {
                      setChanged(true);
                      handleChange(e);
                    }}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}
                  />
                  {errors.email && touched.email && (
                    <div className="input-feedback" style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      {errors.email}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  {!changed && loginError && (
                    <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      <span>{loginError}</span>
                    </div>
                  )}

                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submit}
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                  >
                    Next
                  </Button>
                  <Grid container justify="flex-end">
                    <Grid item>
                      <Link href="/" variant="body2">
                        Already have an account? Sign in
                      </Link>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </form>
              </div>
              <Box mt={5}>
                <Copyright />
              </Box>
            </Container>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default Reg;
```

register2.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { withRouter, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography va riant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      <Link color="inherit" href="sad">
        New
      </Link>{" "}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {"."}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  form: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
  }
}));

const Reg2 = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();
  const [changed, setChanged] = useState(false);
  const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    const { username, password } = values;
    var body = {
      username: username,
      password: password,
      email: history.location.state.email
    };
    console.log(body);
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    const url = "/api/register";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const text = await response.text();
      setSubmitting(false);
      setChanged(false);
      console.log(text);
      if (text === "verifyemail") {
        props.history.push({
          pathname: "/verifyOtp",
          state: { email: body.email }
        });
        // props.history.push(`/verifyOtp/${username}`);
      } else {
        setLoginError("Username or Password is incorrect");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ username: "", password: "", confirmPassword: "" }}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      //********Using Yup for validation********/

      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        username: Yup.string().required("Required"),
        password: Yup.string()
          .required("No password provided.")
          .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
          .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number.")
          .matches(
            /(?=.*[●!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~])/,
            "Password must contain a symbol."
          ),
        confirmPassword: Yup.string()
          .required("Enter to confirm password")
          .oneOf([Yup.ref("password"), null], "Password do not match")
      })}
    >
      {props => {
        const {
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
          isSubmitting,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit
        } = props;
        return (
          <>
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
              <CssBaseline />
              <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                  <LockOutlinedIcon />
                </Avatar>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                  Enter Info
                </Typography>
                <form
                  className={classes.form}
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                  noValidate
                >
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    id="username"
                    value={values.username}
                    label="username"
                    name="username"
                    autoComplete="username"
                    onChange={e => {
                      setChanged(true);
                      handleChange(e);
                    }}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className={errors.username && touched.username && "error"}
                  />
                  {errors.username && touched.username && (
                    <div className="input-feedback" style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      {errors.username}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    name="password"
                    value={values.password}
                    label="Password"
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    autoComplete="current-password"
                    className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}
                    onChange={e => {
                      setChanged(true);
                      handleChange(e);
                    }}
                  />
                  {errors.password && touched.password && (
                    <div className="input-feedback" style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      {errors.password}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    name="confirmPassword"
                    value={values.confirmPassword}
                    type="password"
                    label="Confirm Password"
                    id="confirmPassword"
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    autoComplete="confirmPassword"
                    className={
                      errors.confirmPassword &&
                      touched.confirmPassword &&
                      "error"
                    }
                    onChange={e => {
                      setChanged(true);
                      handleChange(e);
                    }}
                  />
                  {errors.confirmPassword && touched.confirmPassword && (
                    <div className="input-feedback" style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      {errors.confirmPassword}
                    </div>
                  )}

                  {!changed && loginError && (
                    <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      <span>{loginError}</span>
                    </div>
                  )}
                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submit}
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                  >
                    Next
                  </Button>
                </form>
              </div>
              <Box mt={8}>
                <Copyright />
              </Box>
            </Container>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Reg2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make a parent component for register and register2 and store your logic there in which component to display

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await yourApiCall()
      setEmail(response)
    })()
  }, [])

  return email ? <Register /> : <Register2 />
}
```

Comment: I'm not using redux. isn't it possible to do normally in react without using any other complicated library since I only started out?

Answer (score 0):

Initially show the register component or code of that sort. 
Call an api, if the email exists, store flag value in that and do conditional rendering for another component or code of register2.

Initially, `this.state.isEmailExist : false`,

After api call change flag value accordingly. If true then render Register2.

```
const contents = if (!this.state.isEmailExist) {
        return (
            <Register />
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <Register2 />
        )
    }

return(
  <div>{contents}</div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this

```
window.open("https://www.youraddress.com","_self");
```

Make sure to setup the validation.